# Merging files (and file names) in R

Tags: r, file, plyr

I'm trying to merge a directory full of comma delimited text files using R, while also incorporating the file name of each file as a new variable in the data set.

I've been using the following:

```
library(plyr)
file_list <- list.files()
dataset <- ldply(file_list, read.table, header=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Can anyone shed any light on how I'd add the file name for each file read as a new variable within dataset?

Many thanks,

-Jon

Comment: Step 1: Can you write a function that takes a single file name (path) and then read in the file and adds the appropriate column? Step 2: Use that function in `ldply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a wrapper around the `read.table()` function that adds in your filename variable. Something like this should work:

```
read.data <- function(file){
  dat <- read.table(file,header=F,sep=",")
  dat$fname <- file
  return(dat)
}
```

Once there you just need to apply that function across your data files. Since you didn't post any example data I'm not sure what it actually looks like, but for now I'll assume it's clean as can be and that `rbind()` is sufficient to join them together, in which case this example should illustrate that function in action:

```
> data(iris)
> write.csv(iris,file="iris1.csv",row.names=F)
> write.csv(iris,file="iris2.csv",row.names=F)
> dataset <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(pattern="csv$"),read.data))
> head(dataset)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     fname
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa iris1.csv
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa iris1.csv
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa iris1.csv
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa iris1.csv
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa iris1.csv
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa iris1.csv
> table(dataset$fname)

iris1.csv iris2.csv 
      150       150
```

Comment: David, thank you - your solution worked perfectly.  Now I just have to sort out HOW it works...

Comment: You're very welcome - let me know if any part is confusing and I'm glad to elaborate on what is going on. You had about 90% of the solution already in your original post, so if you understand that it shouldn't be that much more to take in. Also, if this answer works for you please click the accept answer button.