# Merge all files using R in a directory while removing the headers and more

Tags: r, csv, rbind

I need to merge multiple .csv files together while removing the header row from each file except from the first file in R Studio.  All the files have the same number of columns and I just need to merge all the rows from each file.

However, this is the complicated part, or what I think is.  The way this data is produced, each file is in its own folder.  So if I have 100 files, then I have 100 individual folders and each folder inside is one file.  The folders are named by each day and the file is named by each day as well.  The only part of the name of the file that changes is the date.  So for example, I'll have a folder named "20160420" with the file inside named "20160420_file".  The next file would be named "20160419" with the file inside named "20160419_file".  And so on.  Each file has a header row, and below it are a days worth of data every minute.

The machines archives data everyday.  We have over 100 machines, and each machine has been producing these files for the past 8 years.  So you can imagine how many files there are and just how long it would take if I did this manually.

How would I write the code in R in R Studio to combine all these files together into one file and remove the duplicate header rows?  Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369435/merging-files-and-file-names-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.files()` or `dir()` with argument `full.names = TRUE` and `recursive = TRUE` to get a vector of file names with paths from across multiple directories.

```
files <- dir(path = "c:/", pattern = "csv", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

Then you can use a loop of some sort to process the files, for example

```
require(plyr)
allData <- ldply(as.list(files), read.csv)
```